# Proving the form of all elements in $ O_{2} (\mathbb {R}) $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Proving that if $ A \in O_{2} (\mathbb {R}) $ then it has one of the two forms. either there is a real number t s.t
$ A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&\!\!\sin t\\-\sin t&\;\cos t\end{pmatrix} $ or $ A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&\!\!\sin t\\\sin t&\;-\cos t\end{pmatrix} $
Then determine the Order of A in each case.

Im kind of stuck on two parts firstly i can't prove that all A are of that form the best i can do is the following.

First notice that we need 2 things by the Def'n.

$\forall A \in O_{2} (\mathbb {R}) $ 1) the rows of A need to form an orthonormal basis 2) determinate of A = $\pm 1$

Now this is an introductory class to abstract algebra but im originally a physics student so i have some intuition/experience on the subject.

So to satisfy 1) its should be sufficient to make each row a unit vector. 
Now the most familiar way for me to write a unit vector for me other than (1,0)  is $(\cos x , \sin x )$ for some x this should imply that our matrix has the form

\begin{pmatrix}\cos x&\!\!\sin x\\\cos y&\;\sin y\end{pmatrix}

Now from the Def'N we note that the rows must be perpendicular to each other to form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb {R^{2}} $ consider $y= x \pm \frac {\pi}{2} $ clearly this will ensure x is perpendicular to y for all choices of x.

\begin{pmatrix}\cos x&\!\!\sin x\\\cos x \pm \frac {\pi}{2}&\;\sin x \pm \frac {\pi}{2}\end{pmatrix}

For the + case we have $ \begin{pmatrix}\cos x&\!\!\sin x\\-\sin x&\;\cos x\end{pmatrix} $  For the minus case we have  $ =\begin{pmatrix}\cos x&\!\!\sin x\\\sin x&\;-\cos x\end{pmatrix} $

this seems to imply that the given A's are in fact in my set but how do i know these 2 matrices are the only form for an element in $ O_{2} (\mathbb {R}) $ can take?

lastly regarding the order i have proved that the order of the Second matrix is 2 for all values of t.

I have also proved that i can make the order of the first matrix and integer i want; I want to belive the order of the first matrix can be infinite as well.

Consider $t \in \mathbb {Q}$ i claim that $ A^{n}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t&\!\!\sin t\\-\sin t&\;\cos t\end{pmatrix}^{n} =\begin{pmatrix}\cos nt&\!\!\sin nt\\-\sin nt&\;\cos nt\end{pmatrix} \forall n \in \mathbb {Z} $

Lastly i claim that,$ \begin{pmatrix}\cos nt&\!\!\sin nt\\-\sin nt&\;\cos nt\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&\!\!0\\0&\;1\end{pmatrix}$ if and only if $nt=2\pi q $ for some integers n and q.

Clearly if $t \in \mathbb {Q}$ then $ nt \neq 2\pi q$ $\space \space \space \forall n, q $ does this imply that when $t \in \mathbb {Q}$ the order of A is infinite?

Comment: I think you meant “orthonormal basis” instead of just “orthogonal basis” near the top, since you then assume that the rows are unit vectors and you use the term “orthonormal basis” later.

Comment: your correct orthonomal basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition that the rows of $A$ form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^2$ implies that $$AA^T=I.\tag{*}$$ The elements of this product are all of the possible dot products of the rows of $A$. This also means that the second condition that you stated is redundant: $\det(AA^T)=\det(A)\det(A^T)=\det(A)^2=1$, so $\det A=\pm1$.

Let $A=\small{\left(\begin{array}{rr}a&b\\c&d\end{array}\right)}$ and expand the above product: $$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{a&c\\b&d}=\pmatrix{a^2+b^2 & ac+bd \\ ac+bd & c^2+d^2}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.$$ The diagonal elements don’t tell us anything we didn’t already know. From the off-diagonals we get $ac+bd=0$. This, taken together with the diagonal elements in $c=\pm b$ and $d=\mp a$. Thus, the only possible forms for $A$ are $\small{\left(\begin{array}{rr}a&b\\-b&a\end{array}\right)}$ or $\small{\left(\begin{array}{rr}a&b\\b&-a\end{array}\right)}$, with $a^2+b^2=1$. Set $a=\cos t$ and $b=\sin t$ and you’re done.

For completeness, I think that you need to substantiate the claims you make about $A^n$, but otherwise the rest of your work looks fine to me, and the final conclusion is sound. We can immediately see from (*) that the second form of $A$ has order two because in that case $A^T=A$ and so $A^2=AA^T=I$, so that case is easy. For the other case, notice the similarity of $A^n$ to $(e^{it})^n$.

Comment: BTW, it’s often more convenient to write the second form as $\small{\pmatrix{\cos2t&\sin2t\\\sin2t&-\cos2t}}$ since it represents a reflection in the line spanned by the vector $(\cos t,\sin t)^T$.

Comment: Yeah i just got tired of typing i made a sounder argument for the case on paper. i like your method of showing completeness. yes 1 and 2 are equivalent just as the argument about matrices you used. appreciate the explanation of the second matrix as well. very good answer!

Comment: @Faust7 You could also get the equations directly from “rows form an orthonormal basis,” but I like to think about this in terms of the matrices. Note, though, that condition 1 implies 2, but they’re not equivalent. $\det A=\pm1$ means that $A$ preserves areas (up to sign), but not necessarily lengths or angles. The orthogonality condition is stronger.